# How to call a UDF in a linq to sql query?

Tags: linq-to-sql

How would the following sql statement translate to a linq query?

```
select ID, 
       Price, 
       dbo.fGetText(DescriptionID, defaultLanguage, currentUserLanguage) 
from Products
```

The UDF fGetText is quite substantial and used throughout the code base, so it needs to be encapsulated (as a UDF or otherwise, perhaps a Linq Expression).

Extra round trips to the database server are not a option. There should only be one query, retrieving 3 fields.

Many thanks in advance for your help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the MSDN article:

[How to: Call User-Defined Functions Inline (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399416.aspx)

A note from the same page:

> Although you can call user-defined
>   functions inline, functions that are
>   included in a query whose execution is
>   deferred are not executed until the
>   query is executed. For more
>   information, see Introduction to LINQ
>   Queries.
>
> When you call the same function
>   outside a query, LINQ to SQL creates a
>   simple query from the method call
>   expression

<s>Also, take a look at this [13 min screencast.](http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/screencasts/screencast/208/User-Defined-Functions-in-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx)</s>

Answer (score 2):

You can add UDF's to a LINQ to SQL DBML file just like you add tables and sprocs.

They then become executable methods on the DataContext.

Google has lots of articles, like <s>[this](http://dotnet.org.za/hiltong/archive/2008/05/21/using-user-defined-functions-udfs-with-linq-to-sql-and-in-linq-to-sql-where-clauses.aspx)</s>.