# How to order by time and time only in C#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-3.0

I have this recorded in SQL Server:

**1- startTime (datetime):  5/2/2009  08:30   (brazilian time format: d/m/y)**

**2- startTime (datetime):  4/2/2009  14:30   (brazilian time format: d/m/y)**

My application just records time... the date it's SQL that generates by itself be getting the date of today.

When I ask VS 2008 to order this datetime fields, it returns me that code #2 is before #1, because 4/2/2009 comes before 5/2/2009.

But, actually I want it to order by time only and ignore the date.

Is it possible??

Thanks!!
André

Comment: You need to give more information. What's doing the ordering? What types are they? You've talked about SQL Server, but then tagged and titled this question with C#.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from d in dates
     orderby d.TimeOfDay
     select d;
```

or

```
dates.OrderBy(d => d.TimeOfDay);
```

---

**Note:** This will work as long as this is plain LINQ and not LINQ-to-SQL. If you're using LINQ-to-SQL to query your database, you'll need something that will translate to SQL.

Comment: Hi, Florian!
It worked! 
When you do this "TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds", VS treats as if all datetime are the same date?
Thanks!!

Comment: Andrea, it's pulling the datetime - time of data and ordering it by the total seconds for that timespan. It ignores the datetime date for the orderby

Comment: @Daniel: your are of course absolutely right. This does work, but can/will result in a performance penalty. You would solve this with a stored procedure? 

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500676/how-to-call-a-udf-in-a-linq-to-sql-query

Comment: Why use the `TotalSeconds` property ? `TimeSpan` implements `IComparable<TimeSpan>`, so you can compare `TimeSpan`s directly : `dates.OrderBy(d => d.TimeOfDay)`

Comment: @Thomas: good point. I changed the answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You might also try fixing your app so it always saves the same base date with the time (like '01/01/1900' or whatever) and then you do not have to do all these slow and inefficient date stripping operations every time you need to do a query.

Or as Joel said, truncate or strip off the date portion before you do the insert or update.

Comment: It's likely that he still needs the date, just not for this particular feature.

Comment: "My application just records time" is what I was responding to. Doesn't sound like he needs the date. But if he does then please disregard my answer.

Comment: No, he specifically said "just records time".  Mostly likely it records time using getdate() or Current_timestamp constructs and the date just came along for the ride.  Most efficient solution is to truncate at time of insertion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't really store a datetime without a date, but you *could* just store the total seconds as an double (using @florian's method).

You'd have to add a second method to convert this back to a date in your object, if you still need a date, such as:

```
public class BusinessObjectWithDate
{
    private string _someOtherDbField = "";
    private double _timeInMS = 0; // save this to the database

    // sort by this? in sql or in code.  You don't really need this 
    // property, since TimeWithDate actually saves the _timeInMS field
    public double TimeInMS {      
        get { return _timeInMS; }
    }
    public DateTime TimeWithDate { // sort by this too, if you want
        get { return (new DateTime(1900,1,1).AddMilliseconds(_timeInMS)); }
        set { _timeInMS = value.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds; }
    }
}

var f = new BusinessObjectWithDate();
MessageBox.Show( f.TimeWithDate.ToString() );  // 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM
f.TimeWithDate = DateTime.Now;
MessageBox.Show( f.TimeWithDate.ToString() );  // 1/1/1900 1:14:57 PM
```

You could also just store the real date time, but always overwrite with 1/1/1900 when the value gets set.  This would also work in sql

```
public class BusinessObjectWithDate
{
    private DateTime _msStoredInDate;
    public DateTime TimeWithDate
    {
        get { return _msStoredInDate; }
        set {
            var ms = value.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
            _msStoredInDate = (new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(ms));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your sql:

```
ORDER BY startTime - CAST(FLOOR(CAST(startTime AS Float)) AS DateTime)
```

Comment: Funny: I read it as "time and time only - in C#". But ordering on the server is probably better here.

Comment: I'm sure something might've been lost in translation - but based on the current wording, it sounds like he's already got the data out of the database and is applying extra ordering to it.